# Hasura Remote schema fails with the protocol error

Tags: kubernetes, istio, hasura, istio-sidecar

I am redirecting the remote schema to an intermittent proxy server. And that proxy server calls the actual remote schema.

excerpt as below

```
  definition:
    url: http://app.metrics:8080/remote-schema
    timeout_seconds: 60
    forward_client_headers: true
    customization:
      root_fields_namespace: metrics
    headers:
      - name: REMOTE_SCHEMA_URL
        value: http://app.team-metrics.svc.cluster.local:8080/graphql
```

It works fine locally and also on docker. But when Its deployed on k8s with istio I get the error as below.

```
Inconsistent object: Error in $: Failed reading: not a valid json value atupstreamconnecterrorordisconnectresetbeforeheaders.resetreason:protocolerror
```

Can someone please help on understanding what is the problem?

Info:  http://app.metrics/ proxy creates a token and passes it to actual remote schema

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TL;DR.**

Passing the header `transfer-encoding: chunked` was creating issue for istio-proxy and I removed it from the response.

**Details:**
The issue was with istio after I analyzed the istio proxy debug logs. Excerpt below.

```
 debug   envoy client    [C1653] Error dispatching received data: http/1.1 protocol error: unsupported transfer encoding
```

And I could see the fix [here](https://discuss.istio.io/t/unsupported-transfer-encoding-error-in-istio-proxy/6021/7).